# Is my alternative proof that the intersection of nested compact sets is nonempty valid?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a collection of nested closed sets in a compact space $X$. Since $A_n$ is closed, it is compact, and consequently limit point compact. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and define a sequence $(x_n)$ where $$ x_n \in A_n \text{ but } x_n \notin A_{n+1} \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} $$ Because each $A_n$ is limit point compact, and contains all but finitely many $x_n$, it contains the limit point of $x_n$. Since every $A_n$ contains the limit point of the sequence, the countable intersection must contain the limit point of $x_n$, hence is nonempty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is good, but there are some problems:

- You say ‘Let $\epsilon>0$’, but then you never use $\epsilon$.
- You want to choose $x_n\in A_n\setminus A_{n+1}$, but this may not be possible: you know that $A_n\supseteq A_{n+1}$, but you don’t know that $A_n\supsetneqq A_{n+1}$. It’s even possible that $A_n=A_1$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.
- Even assuming that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ can be defined, it need not converge; limit point compactness merely tells you that it has a convergent **subsequence**.

All of these can be fixed.

- Just drop ‘Let $\epsilon>0$’; it serves no purpose, and nothing like it is needed.
- Simply choose $x_n\in A_n$ at each stage. Then for all $k\ge n$ you have $x_k\in A_k\subseteq A_n$, so all but finitely many terms of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ are in $A_n$.
- Let $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ be a convergent subsequence of $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ with limit $x$. For each $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $n_\ell\ge m$; clearly $x_{n_k}\in A_m$ for all $k\ge\ell$, so all but finitely many terms of $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ are in $A_m$, and therefore $x\in A_m$. Thus, $x\in\bigcap_{m\ge 1}A_m$, and $\bigcap_{m\ge 1}A_m\ne\varnothing$.